# JSP and JSTL using c:import

Tags: jsp, jstl

Is there a c tag equivalent of the `<%@ include %>` tag?  Basically, when using the `c:import` tag, I find that the included pages cannot use c tags unless I import the jstl/core file on the included page.

Comment: You seem to confusing includes, imports and taglib declarations. Please give us an example of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean in XML syntax?

```
<jsp:directive.include file="relative_url" />
```

If you're looking for JSTL alternative, there isn't any. `<c:import>` is not the same thing - it **evaluates** content before inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

I guess jsp:include could be your thing. not part of the c: taglib, but works fine imo. it's nice for passing dynamic parameters and stuff like that.

http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref1112.html

Comment: `<jsp:include>` is NOT the same as `<%@ include %>` - it **evaluates**  included content rather than including it verbatim